# How is the amount of proof-of-work invested in a chain calculated?

Tags: proof-of-work, consensus

The [bitcoin whitepaper](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf) (page 3) states

> The majority
>   decision is represented by the longest chain, which has the greatest proof-of-work effort invested
>   in it.

I could not find how exactly this difficulty is calculated.

Is it the sum of prefix zeros of the nonces of each block?

---

*I found [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/939/86900) but it is too short for me to understand.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work is calculated as `work = 2^256 / block_target`, as stated in the linked answer, which is the minimum hash value that counts as a valid proof-of-work (note this only changes every 2016 blocks). The source code for this is [src/chain.cpp L#121](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.16.2/src/chain.cpp#L121). The total chain work is the sum of work for all blocks in the chain, and is calculated here: [src/validation.cpp L#3713](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.16.2/src/validation.cpp#L3713). So to visualize, the lower the block target, the more work has been done.

### Example

Block 0 target: `00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`
Block 1 target:
`00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`

**[Block 0](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html?x=00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048):** [`work = (2^256) / <block 0 hash> = 4.295 × 10^9`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%5E256)+%2F+26959946667150639794667015087019630673637144422540572481103610249215)
**[Block 1](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html?x=00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048):** [`work = (2^256) / <block 1 hash> = 4.295 × 10^9`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%5E256)+%2F+26959946667150639794667015087019630673637144422540572481103610249215)

You can see that they have both done the same amount of work. In case of a tie, the following rules apply, see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/37275/60443

- Which one was received first? (This can be different for different clients, which is why the previous rule is applied first.)
- Which one has a larger pointer address? (This is largely random, and different for different clients.)

Comment: An explanation for "block_target" was missing. Now I understand that it is the literal block hash.

Comment: Could you by any chance provide a link to the respective method/line in the Bitcoin source code?

Comment: I've edited my answer, as I was mistaken about using the block hash for the `block_target`

Comment: Also, added links to the source code.